# Can I get mention list via Facebook Graph API, just like we do "@" in a Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook page and when writing post comments, I can mention other groups by adding @. But, can I use Facebook Graph API to get mention list. If yes, what are the permissions I should have and what is the endpoint for getting mention list?

Comment: Not for groups, no. (For pages there’s https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/searching)

Comment: Perfect. I was searching for this link. Thank you!